# Cómo puedo activar el evento Click de un boton que esta dentro de un videoView?

Tags: java, android

alguien que me pueda decir como puedo hacer que un boton pueda ser usado mientras se está reproduciendo un video en un videoView. Lo que necesito es que ese boton permanezca invisible hasta el final del video. Cuando el video termine que el boton aparezca y pueda ser presionado. El problema es que aunque lo presione no ocurre nada.

Código java:

```
video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            if(Capitulo != 0)
            {
                btnSiguienteCapitulo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        ReproductorVideo.this.finish();

                        Intent siguienteCapitulo = new Intent(ReproductorVideo.this, ReproductorVideo.class);

                        siguienteCapitulo.putExtra("Capitulo",Capitulo + 1);
                        siguienteCapitulo.putExtra("Temporada",Temporada);
                        siguienteCapitulo.putExtra("Serie",nombreSerie);

                        startActivity(siguienteCapitulo);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Tengo entendido que OnCompletionListener se activa al terminar el video, pero el boton no funciona y no se porque, les agradecería su ayuda.

Pd: Ya probé usando un Toast y si lo muestra, pero el boton no hace nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El boton va a funcionar en el momento que definas el listener, eso va a ocurrir cuando se cumplan 2 situaciones:

1)Que el video termine de reproducirse, debes asegurarte que no ocurra un error antes de esto.
2)La variable Capitulo debe ser diferente a 0.

Tu implementacion no es comun ya que podrias crear un metodo para realizar el Intent:

```
private void iniciaIntent(){
  ReproductorVideo.this.finish();

                        Intent siguienteCapitulo = new Intent(ReproductorVideo.this, ReproductorVideo.class);

                        siguienteCapitulo.putExtra("Capitulo",Capitulo + 1);
                        siguienteCapitulo.putExtra("Temporada",Temporada);
                        siguienteCapitulo.putExtra("Serie",nombreSerie);

                        startActivity(siguienteCapitulo);
}
```

y mandarlo ejecutar al dar click en el boton y cuando termina el video.

```
btnSiguienteCapitulo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                       iniciaIntent();
                    }
                });

video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            if(Capitulo != 0)
            {
             iniciaIntent();
            }
        }
    });
```

En este ejemplo creas el listener del boton no importando si se completa el video o si `Capitulo !=0`, esto para que siempre funcione el clic del boton.

Comment: Hola, primero que nada muchas gracias Elenasys por toda tu ayuda. El boton sigue sin funcionar, aunque le agregue directamente el intent al OnCompletionListener y asi, funcionó, creo que le quitare el boton ya que el objetivo del mismo era abrir una nueva activity, o en este caso la misma pero con parametros diferentes. Gracias de nuevo.